# Is there any combinatoric method to count the number of bijection $(f,g)$ such that $f(g(n))=g(f(n))$ $(n=1,2,3)$?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to count the number of pairs of bijective functions $(f,g)$ whose domain and range are $\{1,2,3\}$, such that $f(g(n))=g(f(n))$ for $n=1,2,3$. 
I used (almost) brutal-force strategy, and got the answer is $18$.
But I am curious about if there exists a brilliant combinatoric method to solve this problem.
Would you give me a nice idea?

Comment: Is that answer correct?  Every function commutes with the identity, and there are $27$ pairs of the form $(f, id)$ for instance.

Comment: Oh, I missed a critical condition. f and g must be a bijection. I edited the question now.

Comment: Ok, so you have the symmetric group, $S_3$.  Any element of $S_3$ has order $1,2$ or $3$.  The element of order $1$ commutes with everything.  What about an element of order $2$?  Order $3$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am just learning about the first page of modern algebra. But you gave me a nice intuition! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for any finite group $G$, the number of pairs $(x,y)\in G\times G$ for which $xy=yx$ is equal to $|G|$ times the number of conjugacy classes in $G$. Here is a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023455/proving-the-number-of-commuting-pairs-of-elements-in-g-equals-number-of-conjug), which is somewhat combinatorial in nature. Apply this to $G=S_3$, the group of bijective functions on $\{1,2,3\}$. There are $6$ bijections, and $3$ conjugacy classes (corresponding to the three possible cycle types of a permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$), so there are $6\times 3=18$ commuting pairs.

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned above, I have not learned the modern algebra before, and I don't no what conjugacy class means. But thanks to your detailed explanation, I understood how it works! Now, I have one more question. If I set the domain and range to be {1,2,3,...,n}, the answer would be n! times n?

Comment: @okw1124 The number of conjugacy classes in $S_n$ is $p(n)$, the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)), equal to the number of integer partitions of $n$. So the answer for $n$ is $n!\times p(n)$.

Comment: Umm...Can I ask you is there any combinatorial meaning (I mean, we can explain why the partition function appears by words) with that formula?

Comment: @okw1124 Yes, in the symmetric group conjugation is very simple since it is just relabeling elements by a bijection.  if you learn a little bit about permutations factoring into disjoint cycles, you find that two permutations are conjugate iff they have the same cycle structure (number of cycles of each length).  Each partition of $n$ corresponds to a distinct cycle structure, where the lengths of the cycles correspond to the parts summing to $n$.

Comment: Good question, I have no idea! You might have to ask that in a separate question. Something like "Combinatorial proof of formula for number of pairs of commuting partitions?". @okw1124

Comment: @MikeEarnest Okay, I will post a new question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ErickWong I understood what you are saying, but I am confusing at some parts. I think f=(2 1)(3) and g=(3 1)(2) have the same structure, but f(g(1))=3 != 2=g(f(1)). Am I misreading the definition of 'same cycle structure'?

Comment: @okw1124 We’re talking about different things.  I’m explaining when $f$ and $g$ are conjugates, not when $f$ and $g$ commute.  I thought you asked why the partition function appears but maybe reading your comment again that isn’t what you asked.